# Pandas, how to convert number to currency format "XXX,XXX.xx $"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert number XXXXXX.xx to currency format "XXX,XXX.xx $"

Case #1 & #2, using pandas dataframe:

```
      Amount    Currency #1   ($) Currency #2
0    1000000      1,000,000       1,000,000 $
1   97320.25      97,320.25       97,320.25 $
2  9000000.1   9,000,000.10    9,000,000.10 $
```

Which is the best method for this task in terms of code simplicity?

```
df['Currency #1'] = df['Amount'].ToString("###,###,###.00") ??
df['($) Currency #2'] = df['Amount'].apply(lambda x...??
df['($) Currency #2'] = df['Amount'].SomeInternalFunction() ??
```

Comment: I would expect the first option to be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.map('{:,}'.format)`

```
In [191]: df['Amount'].map('{:,}'.format)
Out[191]: 
0    1,000,000.0
1      97,320.25
2    9,000,000.1
Name: Amount, dtype: object

In [192]: df['Amount'].map('{:,} $'.format)
Out[192]: 
0    1,000,000.0 $
1      97,320.25 $
2    9,000,000.1 $
Name: Amount, dtype: object
```

---

```py
In [193]: df['Currency #1'] = df['Amount'].map('{:,}'.format)

In [194]: df['Currency #2'] = df['Amount'].map('{:,} $'.format)

In [195]: df
Out[195]: 
       Amount  Currency #1    Currency #2
0  1000000.00  1,000,000.0  1,000,000.0 $
1    97320.25    97,320.25    97,320.25 $
2  9000000.10  9,000,000.1  9,000,000.1 $
```